# HTML markup in single line in grid

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html, ui

I need to put the value in single line in the grid in the extreme  right of the LWC component.
can anyone help me out for this.
below is the code HTML Markup

```
<template>
    <main class='container'>
        <div class='slds-text-align_center slds-p-bottom_small'>
            <strong>ASDFFF</strong>
        </div>
        <section class='slds-grid slds-wrap'>
            <div class='slds-col slds-size_11-of-12'>
                AGFHD/FGHDH
            </div>
            <div onmouseover={showManaged} onmouseout={showManaged}
                class='number slds-is-relative slds-col slds-size_1-of-12'>
                <div>ASDTE FRIEN</div>
                <section if:true={showManagedPopover} class='managed-popover slds-popover slds-nubbin_left'
                    role='dialog'>
                    
                </section>
            </div>
            
        </section>
    </main>
</template>
```

ASDTE FRIEN should come in the straight line , currently it is coming in up and down in the extreme corner.

[image]

How can I put ASDTE FRIEN in one line on the extreme right corner?

Comment: I think it is likely because you are putting 11 columns for first text and only 1 for the one on the right. I would suggest to have them as 6 columns and align the text to right and also use slds truncate in case the text of the right is large.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your own posts. Your initial content was formatted to be a a valid question here, but then you cleared out all such material and made it just a code dump, which didn't appear to even pertain to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using slds-size class which gives available size for each div anything that goes beyond that size will automatically come on next line  you can give more size to your second div like this and using float on inner div to shift it right like this

```
<section class='slds-grid slds-wrap'>
   <div class='slds-col slds-size_7-of-12'>
                AGFHD/FGHDH
            </div>
            <div onmouseover={showManaged} onmouseout={showManaged}
                class='number slds-is-relative slds-col slds-size_5-of-12'>
                <div style="float:right;">ASDTE FRIEN</div>
                <section if:true={showManagedPopover} class='managed-popover slds-popover slds-nubbin_left'
                    role='dialog'>
                    
                </section>
            </div>
 </section>
```

You can also remove size class

```
<section class='slds-grid slds-wrap'>
   <div class='slds-col'>
                AGFHD/FGHDH
            </div>
            <div onmouseover={showManaged} onmouseout={showManaged}
                class='number slds-is-relative slds-col '>
                <div style="float:right;">ASDTE FRIEN</div>
                <section if:true={showManagedPopover} class='managed-popover slds-popover slds-nubbin_left'
                    role='dialog'>
                    
                </section>
            </div>
 </section>
```